# Operator Overloading Plugin for Java

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I have seen some nice Java compiler [hacks](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/tball/archive/2006/09/hacking_javac.html) wherein you can [replace assertions by throw-exception statements](http://scg.unibe.ch/staff/adriankuhn/javacompiler/forceassertions), you can have auto-generated [properties](http://www.hanhuy.com/pfn/java_property_annotation) for fields and so on...

I was just wondering...

Is it possible to hack Java compiler so that it supports Operator Overloading?

**EDIT :**

It's not that I am missing operator overloading in Java or something. I just want to know whether it is possible to implement it using the hacks mentioned in the links I have given above. So please do not suggest me to switch to some other language like Scala (which I am already learning anyway! :D ).

**EDIT :**

Please just tell me whether it is possible to do it using JSR 269 or something like that. :|

Thanks.

Comment: You should switch to Sca... oh wait...

Comment: I'd go ask on the Project Lombok group - Reinier Zwitserloot and Roel Spilker are doing lots of compiler hacks across a range of tools/compilers, so they'll probably be able to point you in the right direction - http://groups.google.com/group/project-lombok

Comment: It seems to me that one could hack the compiler to do anything possible in compiler theory. Voting down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In response to the edited question, the only way you can implement *true* operator overloading in Java is to add it to the language. This means that you either have to change the compiler to compile your code or write a preprocessor that converts your code to standard Java. For the former, you can download a nearly complete FOSS java implementation from either [GNU](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) or the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) project. For the latter, you can either write your own parser using things like JavaCC etc. (examples are on this [page](http://java-source.net/open-source/parser-generators)) or you can use [JFront](http://www.gginc.biz/jfront/index.html) as a base to add your own syntax.

Comment: Why would you have to modify the language (syntax) to do that? Operator loading is a semantic issue. Shouldn't have to change the parsing stages, other than identifier disambiguation.

Comment: How would you add operator overloading without modifying the syntax? You would either have to add an `operator` keyword or allow `+`, `-` etc as function names. Both require changing what syntax is acceptable.

Comment: I realise you can do this by providing special methods inside of every class, such as __sum__() etc. Note that I only mentioned parsing in conjunction with writing a pre-processor.

Comment: This is not exactly the kind of answer I was expecting but I can't see any better answers coming up. So accepting your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to implement Java operator overloading using JSR 269 with some hacks. Look at java-oo plugins for javac and Eclipse JDT:

http://amelentev.github.com/java-oo/

Answer (score 2):

[JFront](http://www.gginc.biz/jfront/index.html) is a pre-processor for the Java language that allows you to implement operator overloading for your own classes. Sadly, it does not seem to add this ability to standard classes (BigInteger et al. would be a great candidate for this).

Comment: It would be a good trick if it could do it for the `java.*` API classes, but I assume it uses bytecode or source modification, which isn't an option for `java.*` (without some fancy classloader footwork, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

You can use byte code injection to replace a type like *float* with your own type.  This can be done after compilation without changing the compiler.

Comment: How would that help me achieve what I want? Can you please be more clear?

Comment: you could write all your code using float (for example) with operators etc and use byte code replacement to change the code to use your desired type instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want operator overloading, you might consider moving to [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/). Scala code is interoperable with your Java classes and supports operator overloading.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using Groovy libraries since, Groovy already have operator overloading.

https://o24j.dev.java.net/

> The current implementation uses Groovy
>   for the overloading. This approach has
>   one drawback: the groovy libraries
>   have to be delivered with the project.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't allow operator overloading, but considering the links in your question, you may be interested in http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html